# Find an explicit formula for the nth partial sum of the series, and determine whether it converges or diverges.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Consider the series

$$\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \ln\frac{k+1}{k+2}$$

This is what I tried:

Since this is not a geometric series I tried to compute parital sums. So I did:

$$\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \ln({k+1})-ln({k+2})$$

I computed the first couple sums and noiced that as k approached infinity, the sum goes towards negative infinity. So to show this could I say:

$$\lim _{k\to ∞}  = \lim _{k\to ∞} \ln(k)-\ln(k+1)$$

Comment: You have done very well, jut write out the first few terms, the first five or so will do, and you will see the pattern.

Comment: Take the partial sums: start with $\sum_{k=1}^2$, then $\sum_{k=1}^3$, for example, and that should let you figure out $\sum_{k=1}^N$ for any positive integer $N$. Then take $N \to \infty$.

Comment: Looks like you've got plenty of answers here. Just so you know, this type of series is called "telescoping"

Comment: Great I will be sure to look that up and mention it to the class!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$S_1 = \ln(2) - \ln(3)$$
$$S_2 = \ln(2) - \ln(3) + \ln(3) - \ln(4) = \ln(2) - \ln(4)$$
and more generally,
$$S_N = \ln(2) - \ln(N+2)$$

Now take the limit as $N \to \infty$. If this converges, you have your sum. If it diverges, then the series diverges.

Comment: So if I take the limit, I notice it goes towars negative infinity, is that correct?

Comment: Yep. That would do it.

Comment: One more thing if you dont mind, should I edit my question to my final correct answer or should I leave it?

Comment: Usually people do not change the question that they asked once it has been stated clearly. If you like any answer here, you should accept it. That would indicate that you have resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

What you did is fine.

You can also (this is the same idea)
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n \log\frac{k+1}{k+2}
= \log \prod_{k=1}^n \frac{k+1}{k+2}
= \log \frac 2{n+2}
$$

---

A brainless solution:

$$
\log\frac{k+1}{k+2}
= \log\left(1 - \frac{1}{k+2}\right)\sim - \frac{1}{k+2}<0
$$
and as $\sum - \frac{1}{k+2} = -\infty$ the series has limit $-\infty$ as well.

Comment: @Hayden thanks!

Comment: Not a problem, good solution!

Answer (score 1):

Notice that

$$\ln\frac{k+1}{k+2}=\ln\left(1-\frac1{k+2}\right)\sim_\infty-\frac1k$$
and the harmonic series $\sum\frac1k$ is divergent so your series is divergent by comparison.